Movie where a boy and girl whose parents are married kiss
I'm looking for a rather old movie about teens.
I saw the movie around 1998 but perhaps earlier.
I remember a scene from a class room where a girl gets offended not having any breast perhaps and one of the boy goes after her.
Also remember a scene where the girl or boy put their father briefcase into the fridge so their dad thinks it was her mom and they get a divorce.
The boy and a girl I think wanted to date but they had the same parents or their divorced parents got together not sure.
It wasnt a black and white movie, I think it was playing in the US.
The girl had short hair and I think the boy and girl were kissing a couple of times.
What I recall clearly was a quote after the girl put the briefcase to the freezer: the divorced parents kids can kiss right?
It could have been around last years of elementary school.
The girl and boy could have been 12-13 years of age in the movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title
